# Strange warning Value 'x' is always 'null'

Tags: java, sqlite, jdbc

A code below returns me an error and it won't connect to a SQlite db.

```java
public class CardDatabase {

    private String dataBaseName;

    public CardDatabase(String dataBaseName) {
        this.dataBaseName = dataBaseName;
    }

    String databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:./" + dataBaseName; // Value 'dataBaseName' is always 'null' 
    SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource();
```

Although the code below works great.

```java
public class CardDatabase {

    private String dataBaseName;

    public CardDatabase(String dataBaseName) {
        this.dataBaseName = dataBaseName;
    }
    
    SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource();
    String databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:./" + dataBaseName; // swaped two lines
```

Can you help me realize what's the difference between those two codes and why the first one won't compile?

Comment: where are you setting the value to `dataBaseName` ?

Comment: At his point `dataBaseName` isn't initialized. Maybe you actually want a getter that produces `databaseUrl` on the fly?

Comment: @stickybit is right, but I don't know why the second approach *doesn't* show a warning? In my opinion, both should.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`String databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:./" + dataBaseName;` is initialized **before** the constructor is executed.

Meaning it will always use `null` because `dataBaseName` is not *yet* initialized.

But you can move the initialization *into* the constructor. It is also preferred to place the fields before the constructor, and if you never reassign them, you can make them `final`, meaning the can't be overwritten:

```java
public class CardDatabase {

    private final SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource();
    private final String dataBaseName;
    private final String databaseUrl;

    public CardDatabase(String dataBaseName) {
        this.dataBaseName = dataBaseName;
        this.databaseUrl = "jdbc:sqlite:./" + dataBaseName;
    }
}
```

Regarding the error you're receiving: It can simply be that your IDE is not analysing your code thouroughly enough, that it can check that `dataBaseName` is still `null` after the line `SQLiteDataSource dataSource = new SQLiteDataSource();`